# Optimize a vector when constraint coefficients change with decision variables

Tags: r, optimization

Say I have a state of current scores held in a vector:

```
current_score <- c(60, 59, 78, 79, 76)
```

I want to decide what scores to increase. I can increase them to some value (say 95) if I choose that index. Each has an associated cost if chosen.

```
decision <- rep(1, times=length(current_score))
cost <- c(2792, 5207, 1814, 642, 1037)
```

I also want to have the weighted score/cost of the entire vector to meet some minimum goal.

```
goal <- 70
```

How can I find the optimal indexes to choose?

Here's the function I've tried using nonlinear optimization with `optim` but it always returns 0. I'm also not sure how I can implement it with binary constraints (decision vector should be either 1 or 0).

```
fn <- function(decision, current_score, cost, goal)
{
    # if decision = TRUE, score = 95
    # this would provide the constraint coefficients if done in lpSolve
    current_score[which(decision == TRUE)] <- 95

    # calculate weighted score after decision
    wt_score <- sum(current_score*cost)/sum(cost)   
    
    # if decision doesn't meet goal, assign arbitrary large value to reject this choice
    if(wt_score < goal)
    {
        decision_cost <- .Machine$double.xmax
    } else
    {
        decision_cost <- sum(decision * cost)
    } 
    
    return(decision_cost)
}
```

I would normally set this up as a linear program with `lpSolve` but the constraint coefficients change along with the decision variables. I'm not sure if I can implement the binary decision constraints with `optim`. With the approach below, it returns `.Machine$double.xmax` which is obviously incorrect.

```
upper <- rep(1, times=length(decision))
lower <- rep(0, times=length(decision))

result <- optim(par=decision, fn=fn, upper=upper, lower=lower, method=c("L-BFGS-B"), current_score = current_score, cost = cost, goal=goal)
```

For example, `decision = c(1,0,0,0,0)` provides `wt_score = 73.39` and `decision_cost = 2792` so it's a better solution.

Edit: FWIW, this is feasible using a genetic algorithm within Excel, but I would like to do it in R

Below it's mentioned this can be set up as a linear problem. The issue I have is how to implement the constraints because they change as the decision variables change. E.g.,

```
# return a vector that is changed based on the decision variables
constraint_vector <- function(score, x)
{
  score <- score[x==TRUE] <- 95
}

lp_min <- function(score, cost, crvs, goal)
{
  # create a repair vector
  f.obj <- cost
  # not constant, but a function of decision variable x
  f.con <- constraint_vector(score,x)
  f.dir <- c(">=")
  f.rhs <- goal
  
  solution <- lp("in", f.obj, f.con, f.dir, f.rhs, all.bin=TRUE)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a mathematical model can look like:

```
decision variables: x(i): select score i (binary variable)
                    s(i): final score (continuous variable)
data:               cs(i): current (old) score
                    c(i): cost

min cost = sum(i, c(i)*x(i))
    s(i) = cs(i)*(1-x(i)) + 95*x(i)        (1)
    sum(i, s(i)*c(i)) >= 70*sum(i,c(i))    (2)
    x(i) ∈ {0,1}                           (3)
```

This is a linear MIP (Mixed-Integer Programming) Model. This can be implemented and solved using any MIP solver. Even LpSolve.

For the programmers who specialize in copy-paste:

```
current_score <- c(60, 59, 78, 79, 76)  # better name: initial score
cost <- c(2792, 5207, 1814, 642, 1037)  # coefficients
goal <- 70                              # better name: minimum weighted score


library(lpSolve)
n <- length(cost) # number of x(i) variables (and number of s(i) variables)
N <- 2*n # total number of variables (x and s)
M <- 2*n+1 # total number of constraints (binary variables need extra constraints in this interface!!!)

# columns: x first, then s
# rows: constraints (1),(2) and (3) in that order
A <- matrix(0,nrow=M,ncol=N)
for (i in 1:n) {
  A[i,i]       = current_score[i]-95;
  A[i,n+i]     = 1
  A[n+1,n+i]   = cost[i]
  A[n+1+i,i]   = 1
}

rhs <- c(current_score,goal*sum(cost),rep(1,n))
signs <- c(rep("=",n),">=",rep("<=",n))
ints <- 1:n
objs <- c(cost,rep(0,n))
res <- lp("min",objs,A,signs,rhs,T,ints)

res
data.frame(x=res$solution[1:n],s=res$solution[(n+1):(2*n)])
```

This prints:

```
> res
Success: the objective function is 2792 

> data.frame(x=res$solution[1:n],s=res$solution[(n+1):(2*n)])
  x  s
1 1 95
2 0 59
3 0 78
4 0 79
5 0 76
```

Notes:

1. There are much better tools and solvers for expressing and solving these types of models.
2. When implementing this in a particular environment, focus on the mathematical model. This defines the model we want to solve. And it is easier to understand and to reason about than a bunch of code. I.e. the mathematical model is worth more than code, and should be all you need. Implementation in a (programming or other) language is precise, detailed work, but conceptually simple. The heavy lifting is already done. However, more than once, I am disappointed in the dexterity of programmers with this. Way too much hand-holding is being asked for. May be an education problem. I don't know.

Comment: This seems correct, do you have any suggestions on R packages that are well-suited to solving MIPs? Or would I be able to do it in lpSolve where the objective function coefficients are cs(i)*(1-x(i)) + 95*x(i)? The part I struggle with is how to implement the dynamically changing objective coefficients that are a function of x(i)

Comment: This can be solved with lpSolve.

Comment: Ok, but how do you integrate the decision variables into the objective function?

Comment: *The part I struggle with is how to implement the dynamically changing objective coefficients that are a function of x(i)* The objective is simply: `min sum(i, c(i)*x(i))` in this model. This is (as is the rest) linear. There are no "dynamically changing objective coefficients". We don't use penalties, as an LP model supports constraints. So we don't need them.

Comment: Maybe I'm not being clear enough. You reference `x(i)` in your constraint. How does one do that in `lpSolve` ? My prior use, and the documentation at https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lpSolve/lpSolve.pdf use static values. That issue is what I'm speaking to when I bring up `lpSolve` in the original question.

Comment: LpSolve supports linear objectives. Actually, that is the only thing it supports,

Comment: Ex. How would you implement `s(i) = cs(i)*(1-x(i)) + 95*x(i)
    sum(i, s(i)*c(i)) >= 70*sum(i,c(i))` into the form `f.con <- matrix (c(1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2), nrow=2, byrow=TRUE)
f.dir <- c("<=", "<=")`?

Comment: The `cs(i)` value changes depending on the `x(i)` value. That's the 'dynamically changing' element I am referring to. It is not clear to me from the `lpSolve` documentation how to have the `f.con` values be a function rather than a static value.

Comment: Just use high-school level math. `s(i) = cs(i)*(1-x(i)) + 95*x(i)` is `(cs(i)-95)*x(i)+1*s(i)=cs(i)`.  `sum(i, s(i)*c(i)) >= 70*sum(i,c(i))` is `c(1)*s(1)+c(2)*s(2)+,,,+c(n)*s(n) >= 70*sum(i,c(i))`.

Comment: `The cs(i) value changes depending on the x(i) value`. No, it is the old (original) value. The new value is called `s(i)`. Read again the mathematical model and pay attention to the details.

Comment: Understood, but you are still referencing a function within the constraint and not a static value. That function accepts `x(i)` as an argument. The `lpSolve` documentation doesn't indicate it supports this and I'm asking how (specifically, not as a mathematical concept) one would implement it. I understand the concept, and can implement it fine in other platforms like Excel. I'm asking how to do the same in R.

Comment: There are no functions in this formulation, only linear expressions.

Comment: Right here: `sum(i, s(i)*c(i)) >= 70*sum(i,c(i))` is a constraint, no?


And `s(i)` is a function of the decision variables `x(i)`, correct?  `s(i) = cs(i)*(1-x(i)) + 95*x(i)`


So how would I write `f.con <- ` to implement `s(i)` ?

Comment: s(i) is just another decision variable. See the mathematical model.

Comment: This is becoming a circular discussion. I appreciate the effort, but it doesn't really seem to answer the question I had to continually point back to the mathematical model. Like I said, I understand that concept, it's the implementation that's hanging me up. Continually pointing to the model does not help in that regard.

Comment: Yes, the mathematical model is the important part. Once you understand that, the rest becomes trivial (e.g. transcribe it in matrix format for LpSolve).

Comment: Can you show me the trivial part then with `lpSolve`? That would answer this question. I can formulate the problem elsewhere, just not in the format for `lpSolve`. I would prefer to use R since Excel is limited to 200 decision variables. For example, in Excel I can easily write a formula that changes the constraint coefficients based on `x(i)` just like you show in your model with `s(i)`. However, I do not know how to do the same thing with `lpSolve`. The example documentation only uses static values.

Comment: Appreciate the help. Based on the unsolicited commentary, you seem very unhappy. I hope you find a brighter day ahead, my friend.

Answer (score 0):

if a decision can only be combination of 5 binary choices, there are only 32 combinations to search exhaustively.
evaluate all of them explicitly.
use this to get started :

```
do.call(expand.grid,rep(list(0:1),5))
```

p.s. i believe you mislabled the argument score of your function its never referenced outside of the function definition

Comment: Thank you for the correction. Yes, while i know this toy problem can use an exhaustive search, I would like a method that scales better than an exhaustive search as the problem space gets larger. In reality, this would need to apply to hundreds or thousands of binary choices.